# How to do I animate a coin in swift to show that it is spinning, using multiple images?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation

I does not have to be real 3d,thanks. I tried to use a gif image but it did not work and just displayed the image.

Comment: if you have a gif you can use this library https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Comment: Does it work with swift

Comment: It should. Just read apples documentation on how to use objective c code in swift

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UIImageView`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/animationImages

```
// imageView is a UIImageView
// images is an array of UIImages

imageView.animationImages = images
imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 10
imageView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: imageView.animationImages = [3039651.png, 3039668.png]
    imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 10
    imageView.startAnimating()

Comment: `images` is an array of `UIImage`. e.g. `let image = UIImage(named: "3039651")!`.  Obviously for many images the array would be best filled in a loop.

Comment: is this better let image1 = UIImage(named: "3039651.png")
    let image2 = UIImage(named: "3039668.png")
    imageView.animationImages = [image1, image2]
    imageView.animationDuration = 1.0
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 10
    imageView.startAnimating()
sorry I am new to swift